# Very large HTML/PHP website to make resposive

Tags: responsive-design, seo

I manage a few web sites which are very large, something like 300+ pages in different languages, the pages contains products catalogues with many images, lightbox galleries, downloadable PDF's, slides, etc.

The sites were made few years ago and all the pages are "hand made", no CMS or software like that.

The sites shows wonderfully on tablets and cell phones (in landscape orientation) but I stumbled on this Google test of the not-responsive-friendly nightmare that will downrank these sites.

I tried working on css but being an old site I saw that it will be better to rebuild it than trying to make it responsive, but actually I am not able in terms of time to rebuild them from zero.

The only thing that came to my mind is to make a parallel essential website like m.domain.com where to send all the clients with phones or tablets.

In terms of SEO, is that a working solution or it will be a waste of time?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SEO is hardly a definitively answerable topic here. Who knows how Google will punish you today or tomorrow?

Comment: Personally I hate it when there are separate domains for mobile devices, instead of detecting the device and serving different CSS.

Answer (score 0):

It is a solution for Google, but not for Bing. Make sure you have a canonical pointing from your mobile page to your desktop version (more about mobile seo in a [post](https://seosummaries.com/expertise/mobile-site-seo-tips-strategy.html) I maintain).